# How do I combine two vectors of vectors element-wise in clojure?

Tags: list, vector, clojure

Suppose I've got:

```
'[[c c c]
  [y y y]
  [m m m]]
```

and

```
'[[r g b]
  [r g b]
  [r g b]]
```

and I'd like to have:

```
'[[[c,r] [c,g] [c,b]]
  [[y,r] [y,g] [y,b]]
  [[m,r] [m,g] [m,b]]]
```

What is the elegant way to do this in clojure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(def a '[[c c c]
         [y y y]
         [m m m]])
(def b '[[r g b]
         [r g b]
         [r g b]])

(mapv (partial mapv vector) a b) ;; will work with arbitrary number 
                                 ;; of equal sized arguments

;=> [[[c r] [c g] [c b]] [[y r] [y g] [y b]] [[m r] [m g] [m b]]]
```

Comment: Ooh, I have just learned two new things and I also feel like a complete idiot. Thanks Alex!!

Comment: As far as I know `for` won't do element-wise iteration of multiple collections, it nests iteration of multiple collections rightmost fastest. `for` also returns a lazy-seq although I guess in principle a  `forv` could be created analogous to `mapv`

Answer (score 4):

Consider adopting [core.matrix](https://clojars.org/net.mikera/core.matrix) for stuff like this.

It will manipulate nested vectors as matrices quite happily, but also does much more powerful stuff if you need it (for example, support for accelerated native matrix libraries via JBLAS). It's shaping up to be the definitive library/API for matrix computations in Clojure.

In this case you can simply use "emap" to apply a function element-wise to two matrices:

```
(use 'core.matrix)

(def cym '[[c c c]
           [y y y]
           [m m m]])

(def rgb '[[r g b]
           [r g b]
           [r g b]])

(emap vector cym rgb)

=> [[[c r] [c g] [c b]] 
    [[y r] [y g] [y b]] 
    [[m r] [m g] [m b]]]
```

Comment: Hi Mike, (use 'core.matrix) gives me: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate core/matrix__init.class or core/matrix.clj on classpath

Comment: core.matrix is pretty bleeding-edge... you might try adding [net.mikera/core.matrix "0.0.11"]
to your `project.clj`.

Answer (score 3):

`partition` and `interleave` get you there, as seqs:

```
(def a '[[c c c]
         [y y y]
         [m m m]])
(def b '[[r g b]
         [r g b]
         [r g b]])

(map (partial partition 2) (map interleave a b))
;=> (((c r) (c g) (c b)) 
;    ((y r) (y g) (y b))
;    ((m r) (m g) (m b)))
```

If for some reason you need to convert the answer to nested vectors, it might be worth a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044181/into-or-vec-converting-sequence-back-to-vector-in-clojure).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another implementation:

```
(defn combine-vectors [& vecs]
  (apply map (partial map vector) vecs))
```

Replace `map` with `mapv` to get vectors instead of lazy seqs out of this.